# Updating Like Button After Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a Like button. It's working fine. After Like button completes it's functionality I'm trying to update the button text (Like to Liked) without refreshing the page, but problem is that It's updating the every single Like button on the webpage (until I refresh the page) not just the one I clicked on . . .

Here's that success function in AJAX call,

```
$('.like-click').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var this_ = $(this);
var quesURL = this_.attr('like-href');
$.ajax({
    url: quesURL,
    method: 'GET',
    data: {},
    success: function (data) {
        var like_text = $(data).find('.like-click').html();
        $('.like-click').html(like_text);
    }
})
});
```

Here's the HTML,

```
{% for data in datas %}
     ....
     <a class="like-click" like-href="...">{% if user in Likes %}Liked{% else %}Like{% endif %}</a>
     ....
{% endfor %}
```

How can I update only the button I clicked not all of them ?

Comment: You have to use `id` instead of `class` here.

Comment: @Mamun Sir, now it's working for first element only . . . ?

Comment: Yes, it will only work for only the matched `id`.

Comment: Post full ajax and html.

Comment: @Mamun Sir, please see the updated the Question . . .

Comment: See the answer. No need to use `id`. Hope that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your success function generically updates all class elements ".like-click". If you want to update a single element identify the element in a unique way with an unique id. When clicking emit the id and then when updating filter to only update the element with that id.